# How to get all owners and balances of an NFT with infura?

Tags: go-ethereum, infura

I'm trying to get all owners and balances of a specific NFT with infura,

I am using this API `nft.api.infura.io` as follows

```
curl -X 'GET' \                                                                    
  -u <API_KEY>:<API_KEY_SECRET> \
'https://nft.api.infura.io/networks/1/nfts/0x28472a58a490c5e09a238847f66a68a47cc76f0f/1/owners' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'
```

However, the total owners is more than 5000 and the `pageSize` is only 100 so only 100 owners and balances are attached in the response.

Can anyone please help me how to get all more than 5000 owners?

Thank you so much.